# Por que "alert", "confirm" e "prompt" travam o carregamento independente da ordem de definição?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Gostaria de entender porque, quando usamos as funções `alert`, `confirm` ou `prompt`, as mesmas sempre causam uma espécie de "congelamento" na tela.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um `alert`e, em seguida, tenho uma `div` com um estilo definido. O estilo da `div` só ficará visível depois que eu fechar o `alert`.

```html
<script>alert('oi')</script>
<div style="background-color: black;height: 50px">
  
</div>
```

Pensava que se travava da ordem como as coisas foram definidas, mas parece que não é bem isso:

```html
<div style="background-color: black;height: 50px"></div>

<script>alert('oi')</script>
```

Eu já notei também que, em outros casos, quando você tem uma definição dinâmica de criação de elementos, a mesma coisa acontece.

No exemplo abaixo, eu já tenho um elemento criado, porém, depois de um tempo, eu crio outro dinamicamente e, em seguida, chamo a função `confirm`.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Nova div';
  document.body.appendChild(div) 
  confirm('oi')
}, 200)
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;height: 50px"></div>
```

O resultado é que, mesmo eu definindo `document.body.appendChild` antes de `confirm`, o `appendChild` parece ser executado apenas depois do fechamento de `confirm`.

- Por que os diálogos nativos do Javascript "travam" o processo de criação de elementos e definições de estilo?
- Tendo em vista que as vezes isso causa um "brancão" indesejado na tela, como eu poderia chamar `alert`, `confirm` ou `prompt` sem que isso interfira no carregamento da página?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Por que “alert”, “confirm” e “prompt” travam o carregamento?

Porque é uma caracteristica da linguagem...

Essa funcionalidade foi criada assim, no tempo dos dinossauros, e não mudou mais porque toda a gente sabe que funciona assim e mudar isso iria quebrar código que conta com essa característica da linguagem. Como o JavaScript corre num thread único e esses métodos esperam resposta do utilizador, tudo pára à espera da ação do utilizador.

A razão pela qual o estilo não é mostrado é porque o HTML não é mostrado antes do JavaScript ser lido. Não aparece estilo, nem conteúdo. É a maneira como o browser monta a página. ([exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/tfpjhd5q/))

Comment: Mas por que, no segundo caso, o `alert` é exibido antes da DIV?

Comment: @jbueno tem a ver com a maneira do browser montar a página, juntei um exemplo.

Comment: @Sergio Aproveitando, [neste update do seu exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/tfpjhd5q/1/) eu altero a cor pelo próprio JS. Mas mesmo assim ele não altera a cor. É o mesmo motivo de renderizar o HTML primeiro?

Comment: @Randrade exato. O JavaScript já sabe que a cor mudou mas o browser ainda não chegou ao momento de renderizar a página.

Comment: 1 ano se passou e ninguém notou o "dinaussauros" né @Sergio :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters :o

Answer (score 9):

Isso acontece porque o JS original é síncrono e o JS precisa travar a execução no `confirm`, por exemplo, para que o seu resultado seja colocado na variável e que possa ser usado logo na linha de baixo.

Sobre a segunda pergunta: o browser é divido em várias partes, uma delas é a engine de JS e outra é a parte que desenha as coisas na tela. Elas não são síncronas. O JS pode ter mandado aparecer algo na tela, mas o browser só vai desenhar mesmo na tela quando acontecer o próximo refresh, e isso depende de várias coisas, incluindo a capacidade do dispositivo de desenhar coisas na tela rapidamente.

Existe uma função nova `requestAnimationFrame` que permite executar uma função junto quando o browser está fazendo o refresh.

Answer (score 8):

Acho que as respostas postadas já respondem bem. Só para complementar, como alternativa pode criar um diálogo seu que não bloqueie. Em geral usará [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) ou [Promisses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). O que agora tem se tornando bem padrão.

O [jQuery faz isso](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma [pequena gambiarra](https://jsfiddle.net/gmfz3sqz/) com `setTimeout` pode vir a calhar :p

Comment: Pensei em postar algo assim, mas como não sabia se tinha algum problema que fizesse isso não ser a melhor ideia, preferi deixar sem.

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade esse comportamento depende do browser que voce está a usar.

Vou passar a descrever o comportamento para os browsers mais usados:

> Chrome(1) - Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)
>
> Firefox(2) - Firefox 49.0.2
>
> Edge(3) - Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0
>
> Opera(4) - Opera 41.0.2353.56
>
> IE(5) - Internet explorer 11.447.14393.0
>
> Safari(6) - Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)
>
> Chrome no android(7) - Chrome 53.0.2785.124
>
> Era para ter testado também com o firefox no android e com o safari
>   no ios mas nao é possivel correr o código de snippets do stackexchange neles.

Cenário 1 - `<script>` antes de `<div>` - Todos os browsers tem comportamento identico

Cenário 2 - `<div>` antes de `<script>`

1. Mostra a mensagem. Bloqueia. Mostra a div
2. Mostra os dois práticamente ao mesmo tempo
3. Mostra os dois práticamente ao mesmo tempo
4. Mostra a mensagem. Bloqueia. Mostra a div
5. Mostra os dois práticamente ao mesmo tempo
6. Mostra a mensagem. Bloqueia. Mostra a div
7. Mostra a mensagem. Bloqueia. Mostra a div

Cenário 3 - Com timeout. todos os browsers tem o mesmo comportamento.

Podemos entao concluir que últimamente depende da implementacao do engine de javascript do browser / carregamento do DOM no cenário 2.

[Uma pergunta bastante relacionada a esta na comunidade inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup), pergunta onde a gente deve de meter blocos de `<script>` no html.

A resposta que foi dada é que deve ser no final do documento html para o dom ser carregado. e no seu javascript poder aceder a qualquer elemento da sua página.

Ou seja se o dom for carregado e apresentado antes do seu script (como acontece no firefox edge e ie) voce tem o comportamento descrito (em que aparecem os dois ao mesmo tempo), senao o browser interpreta o script e corre-o.

Comment: Acho uma boa iniciativa você ter feito testes. O único problema nesse caso é que daqui a 3 ou 6 meses sua resposta já poderá estar obsoleta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu sei que pode. Mas ninguem nas respostas referiu que o comportamento pode ser diferente dependendo da versao do browser.

Comment: Foi exatamente esse o ponto que eu gostei. O Javascript e o Css sempre tem esses probleminhas de variação de acordo com os browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Porque essa funções a que se refere, internamente possuem um conjunto de sub-rotinas e uma delas é : *"Para tudo! Mostra o Alert e espera uma entrada do usuário"*, e cada uma terá seu comportamento peculiar...

Comment: `alert` não espera a entrada do usuário, a não ser que você seja considerando o click em `"ok"`. Talvez a palavra correta fosse "iteração do usuário" :p

Comment: Não, é entrada mesmo... A Computação é inteira é baseada em I/O, input/output, entrada/saída...Nesse caso estou considerando o "ok", o "x" e o "checkbox" como entradas, mas como citado pelo @bigown, se vc criar o seu poderá ser até o movimento do mouse, ou num futuro ultrapassado o "Piscar do olhos"....